# Unable to start MongoDB with NUMA interleave

Tags: oracle, mongodb, linux, numa

When I login to Mongo Shell in my production server, running Oracle Linux v7, I see the message:

> WARNING: You are running on a NUMA machine.

To address this, I have used the init script as suggested here : https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/rpm/init.d-mongod.

I have restarted mongod as well as the machine, yet it looks like my mongod does not start with the `--interleave=all` setting and I see the same warning on start up. Any help?

Comment: Check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/293468/how-should-i-start-mongodb-on-a-numa-machine

Comment: thank you @jjussi. I have added an init.d/mongod file that has the NUMACTL args. I have restarted mongod and the vm instance multiple time to no effect.

Comment: And you cannot disable NUMA for that machine?

Comment: Nope. From where I am, BIOS is totally out of reach, if that's what you mean.  I have full control on MongoDB though.

Comment: So your startup command is `/usr/bin/numactl --interleave=all /usr/bin/mongod`? You can test that directly at command line.

Comment: @JJussi thanks... I got this working finally... my problem was that there was a service file here:  /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service and no matter what I did that took precedence over my init script. I finally realized this and modified the startup command in the service file.

Comment: Made that as an answer, so you can select it as the right answer. ;-)

Comment: Does this make a big difference in performance? More than 20%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your startup script doesn't actually use `numactl` command to start mongod.

Your startup command should be:

```bash
/usr/bin/numactl --interleave=all /usr/bin/mongod
```

See also a similar question at AskUbuntu: [How should I start MongoDB on a NUMA machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293468/how-should-i-start-mongodb-on-a-numa-machine)

Comment: You could explain why this works

Comment: As original question maker wrote, his startup script didn't actually use numactl command to start mongod

Comment: and it was ignoring my init.d script since there was a service file